# How can I retrieve data from firebase (Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am beginner and I would like to use swift as my programming language.

user can add register users and transfer money to each other, therefore when user type the photo number and email, the app can check if the typed number is registered in the firebase system

Any simple way to search if the user exist, thanks a lot

Here's the structure of the database

[image]

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var tref: DatabaseReference!

var handle : DatabaseHandle!

var usersArray = [NSDictionary?]()
var filteredUsers = [NSDictionary?]()
var user : NSDictionary?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.picker.isHidden = true
    tref = Database.database().reference()
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    self.handle = self.ref?.child("users").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("contact").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let item = snapshot.value as? String {
            self.pickerdata.append(item)
            self.picker.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    })
    self.picker.delegate = self
    self.picker.dataSource = self

    tref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "phone").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
        self.usersArray.append(snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)
    })
    print(usersArray.count)

}

 @IBAction func ContactChange(_ sender: UITextField) {
    filteredContent(searchText: contactText.text!)
    print(filteredUsers.count)
    print(usersArray.count)
    print("ARRAY")

}

func filteredContent(searchText: String){
    self.filteredUsers = self.usersArray.filter{ user in
        let username = user!["phone"] as? String
        return (username?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
    }
}

func findUsers(text: String){
    self.handle = ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "phone").queryStarting(atValue: contactText.text!).queryEnding(atValue: contactText.text!+"\u{f8ff}").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if let item = snapshot.value as? String {
            self.contact.append(item)
        } else{
            print("error")
        }
    })
}
```

The code above doesn't work much. Thanks so much for helping

Comment: The question is pretty unclear and you are going to have some difficulties with that code. Firebase is asynchronous and the code within the two Firebase closures is going to execute after the print fires and the usersArray may get populated before (or after) the pickerData does and/or the picker is reloaded. Are you asking how to see if a user exists by their photo number?

Comment: Yes this is the question, thx bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little unclear but I think what the OP is asking is:

> how to see if a user exists by their phone number?

If that's what's being asked, a node can be retrieved by query'ing for a child of that node. For example, let's create a query on the users node to find the child that contains the name: Kam querying by phone

```
let usersRef = firebaseRef.child("users")
let query = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "phone").queryEqual(toValue: "2330504")
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        //need to iterate in case we find more than one match
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
            let name = dict["name"] as! String
            print("found \(name)")
        }

    } else {
        print("not found")
    }
}
```

When this code is run it would print

```
found Kam
```

assuming the phone number is 2330504